# How much previous version is worth

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration

I have just moved to magento, and I have seen magento 2 is out for a while, so it seem obvious that I should start with magento 2. But considering that many customers in the market will not adopt change and migrate to magento 2, is it wise to start from magento 1.9 and then move to magento 2.

I say this because many people who hire magento developer usually want developer for existing system, and chances of starting on new system is quite slim. 
And another thing to consider is that structure of both versions are different as well.
And to migrate from previous to new version, we need knowledge of both systems.

So how much beneficial would it be to start from 1.9 and move to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a very compelling reason not to (some absolutely vital functionality that isn't available on M2 yet), start on Magento 2. If you start on M1 with the intention of migrating to M2 later, you'll just be doubling the amount of work you have to do in the process.

M2 is reasonably stable, and will only be getting better over time. M1 is stable, but stagnate; you won't be getting any extensive updates.

Comment: Thank Ryan, can you provide any good resource or books on magento 2, i would like to start on theming

Comment: For an overview of M2 theming, check out the official course: https://magento.com/training/catalog/core-principles-theming-magento2